# I can't seem to be able to draw the simplest thing with TikZ on LyX, but with MiKTeX it works

Tags: tikz-pgf, lyx

I was trying to make a plot of something for my physics homework and found [This](http://www.chelseas-roost.co.uk/resources/lyx/PlottingGraphsInLyX) article explaining how to do it. I called all the necessary packages (I tried both tikz and pgfplots) in the preamble in the settings, but after inserting a TeX code box and writing this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and I got nothing when trying to get the PDF. It seemed weird, because I installed all the packages it asked me to. I also tried this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

just to see if I could draw a simple vector, without any luck. I figured maybe it's a problem with the TeX processing or something, so I tried:

```latex
\Huge BANANA
```

and I got what you'd expect, so it's not that. I tried inserting a child document by saving the TeX code in another file, but it still didn't work. At this point I figured maybe my LaTeX processor MiKTeX was the one making the problems, so I tried compiling the file by itself, and it worked fine.

I know I could get the result I want with another program to create a graph and just add it (which is what I'll probably end up doing for now), but this probably has a solution (hopefully not one that I didn't find when searching for one).

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot to add it in my post... I'll edit my post with a complete document

Comment: What happens if you add BANANA after `\end{tikzpicture}`? What output do you get?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out... I didn't mention something that I haven't figured would be relevant, turns out it is - I was writing a document in Hebrew, and all I had to do is change to English before adding the TeX box... Sorry for the spam and thank you for your time! I'll answer the question now